# Localized abdominal pain after a short run

Tags: running, pain

I had gone on my first run in months last night, and aside from the expected soreness in the legs and calves, I've got a rather sensitive spot on my abs, about an inch down and left (from my perspective, looking down) of my navel. I wouldn't necessarily call it pain, just abnormally sensitive. The rest of my abs are slightly sore, nothing that like this little button of 'ow'.

Some background: I used to run pretty regularly, not marathon level, but upwards of 5 miles a day. Last night, I ran just over 2 miles at a slow pace of ~11 min / mi. Just trying to get my legs back under me.

Any ideas as to the cause of the pain?

Comment: Not really, the problem is it could be anything from a muscle strain to a hernia. If it's painful, I would have it checked out.

Comment: Agree with JohnP, get it checked out.

Comment: Saw several docs, they couldn't find any indication of a hernia. They said it was likely a muscle strain, but keep an eye on it. The pain has reduced, it's not noticeable unless I poke at it like the anti-Pillsbury Dough Boy. Not a 'woo hoo', just a sad. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had that pain, same spot you describe. Went to the doctor's several times, they didn't know anything, suggested I go to emerg the next time I got it, so I did. They didn't have a clue either.

My best guess is food stuck in the small intestine, as that's around where it has to go around a bend, and I don't experience it when I'm focusing on eating a lot of fiber.